# Regex for counting occurrences of a string within a single cell in Google Sheets

Tags: regex, google-sheets

I have a Google Sheet filled with data and cells, and would like to get the number of times a string appears in a particular cell, as well as how many times a string appears in total for a single column. For example, I am trying to count the number of "of" strings in a column as follows:

```
=COUNTA(FILTER('Data Sheet'!G3:G313, REGEXMATCH('Data Sheet'!G3:G313, "of")))
```

However, this just returns the number of cells with an "of". How do I get the total count of "of" strings.

Comment: You will have to write a custom function.

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this

```
COUNTA(SPLIT(REGEXREPLACE('Data Sheet'!G3:G313,"of","$ ."),"$"));
```

You can replace "of" with a symbol "$", and then count number of symbols in it.

Comment: Have you tested this?

Answer (score 1):

The COUNTA answers do not actually work. They missing two things (1) **REGEXPREPLACE** does not work directly on a range (2) the result is off by one.

Try this:

```
=COUNTA(SPLIT(REGEXREPLACE(concatenate('Data Sheet'!G3:G313),"of",".$$."),"$$",false()))-1
```

This works for me, but it does not work if the concatenation of values might result in artificial matches. In fact, the basic assumption approaches like this is that you are able to choose `"$"` or `".$$."` or an alternative that won't result in artificial matches.

Answer (score 0):

For a single cell, you can use

```
=(len(G3)-len(substitute(G3, "of",)))/2
```

To count the number of occurrences in a column try

```
=sum(ArrayFormula(if(len(G3:G), (len(G3:G7)-len(substitute(G3:G, "of",)))/2,)))
```

Note: 2 refers to the number of characters of the string to count( "of")

Change range to suit and see if that works?

Answer (score 0):

to work well, better:

```
=COUNTA(SPLIT(REGEXREPLACE('Data Sheet'!G3:G313,"of",".$$."),"$$",false()));
```

because:
$$ to avoid cells containing the character.
.$$. to prevent null strings afecct the result
false to say $$ is one coincidence, not two separators characters